# PhoneGap & Sencha Touch 2 loading screen

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

Im building a sencha touch 2 phonegap based app and my app pulls JSON data from a remote server. Currently the phonegap native load screen appears until the device is ready, and then the sencha touch 2 load screen appears until sencha touch 2 is ready.

I'd like the native phonegap screen to appear until everything is loaded, including sencha touch 2.

I've googled around for a solution, but can't find anything. Is there a method available to tell phonegap to wait for sencha touch 2 before hiding the load screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS you can set AutoHideSplashScreen to NO in your Cordova.plist, and later hide your splashscreen using

`navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

On Android you can do something similar, Simon Mac Donald has a guide on this:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.nl/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

Comment: Thanks, this will suffice. Hope I can find a similar solution for android.